# Editing an NSXMLDocument without escaping special characters

Tags: objective-c, xml, cocoa

I have an NSXMLDocument that I am editing and then saving out. The problem is, it's escaping my & and <.

```
NSArray *nodes = [document nodesForXPath:@"JDF/JDF/ResourcePool/od:Ticket/od:Parameter/DefaultOutputOption" error:nil];
[[nodes objectAtIndex:0] setStringValue:@"34&quot;"];
NSLog(@"%@", [[nodes objectAtIndex:0]stringValue]);
[[nodes objectAtIndex:1] setStringValue:@"1<2"];
NSLog(@"%@", [[nodes objectAtIndex:1]stringValue]);
NSData *xmlData = [document XMLDataWithOptions:NSXMLNodePreserveAll];
[xmlData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

In console I'm getting what you'd expect from the NSLog statements:

```
2011-09-06 16:05:56.480 My App[14369:707] 34&quot;
2011-09-06 16:05:56.482 My App[14369:707] 1<2
```

But in my XML Document I get:

```
34&amp;quot;
1&lt;2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is frustrating, I've tried setting the document kind to Text. The output options to every available option, and it's still serializing the & and the <. It doesn't serialize " or > though and I'm not sure why. It there no way to get the XMLDocument data without serializing it?

Answer (score 0):

Technically you're not doing anything wrong. When you set the text value for a node, you should use the raw, unescaped form. When the nodes are serialized to XML, some characters will be escaped, e.g. " will become &quot; and < will become &lt;.

I guess what really want to enter as text in the first node is `34"`, which in XML serialized form is `34&quot;`.

Comment: Ironically when I do that it leaves the " unescaped.